# Is $f$ Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am having trouble with proof for this statement:
Let $V$ be Vitali set, is function $f : \Re \rightarrow \Re$  Lebesgue measurable?

$$ 
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-7x-4 &x \in V \\ 
0 &x \notin V 
\end{array} 
\right. $$

I'm completely lost and I don't know where to begin, if $f$ would be continuous function it would be measurable, but it isn't continuous. It seems to me that this function is in fact measurable, but I don't know how to proof that and how to start. Thank you for any advice.

EDIT: I misplaced `in` sign, sorry

Comment: Hint: what is $f^{-1}(\{0\})$?  Is this measurable?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Correct me if I'm wrong, but from my calculations it is in fact measurable.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry, but I've misplaced in sign in my problem, now it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ were a measurable function then $\Bbb R\setminus [\, (f^{-1}\{0\})\cap ( \Bbb R\setminus \{-4/7\})\,]=V$ would be a measurable set.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's more clear now, but last question, why we need to exclude -4/7? I understand that inverse function is equal to $-(x+4)/7$, but isn't real numbers without inverse function on zero enough to proof equality to V?

Comment: I just wanted to be brief, and to ignore whether $-4/7$ might or might not belong to $V$....If $f^{-1}\{0\} =(\Bbb R \setminus V)\cup \{-4/7\}$ is a  measurable set then obviously so is $\Bbb R \setminus V$ & hence so is $V.$